# How to enable cache logging in solr

Tags: caching, logging, solr

I am using solr 4.10. I have to count requests for documents. According to my knowledge, when solr serves documents against a query, it copies it to cache also.

Meanwhile, if the same query is run again, then it is served from cache. No information are logged when a query is served from cache. How do I count serverving from cache. I think, it would be the simplest solution to log cache request also. Then How to do logging for cache.

Answer (score 1):

Within the Solr admin UI you have statistics about the caches in your cores. This is already baked in. However this is not persistent. When the core is reloaded or the server restarted this information is lost.

[image]

Comment: Dear respected, I said I need logged info so that I can count impression correctly and not what you have informed. It showing current status of cache but I ham saying about logs

Comment: Then I do not understand what you are seeking. These cache statistics have that information aggregated. How many documents/field accesses/filter queries/queries have been served from the cache and how many missed. Do you want to know exactly which query has hit/missed individually?

Comment: yes you are write. I have to know exactly what documents are served from cache for a query